# ngrok status error -looks like ngrok tunnel doesnot exist anymore

Tags: c#, .net-core, botframework, ngrok

We are using ngrok, bot emulator to debug our code from local machine.But most of the time ngrok tunnel status shows error and we have no means to debug our bot code from local emulator. But if I look at https://status.ngrok.com, it is always showing in green and  all systems as operational.

**Question1 :** Is there any other alternative ways to debug my bot code(dotnet core,botframework,C#) code.

**Question2:** The ngrok error I see on my bot emulator(screenshot below) has anything to do with my local system or network? Is there a way to fix such issues.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ngrok only supports running two instances simultaneously. This is true for both free and paid accounts (regardless of the tier).

If you are running two instances already, then you will need to stop one of them. Once done, close the Emulator chat tab and re-open it to start a new chat instance that will utilize ngrok.

Another possibility, if you are not running two instances of ngrok, is you have not provided the path to the ngrok executable in the Emulator settings (see below).

Both of these will cause the error you are receiving.

[image]

Lastly, it's possible your network is blocking ngrok if you are behind a firewall or VPN. I don't believe this to be the case as I believe the returned failure message would be different, but it's a possibility and worth checking.

Hope of help!